# STM32F407 FSMC & ILI9341 – 8 bit bus width works, 16 bit doesn't

Tags: stm32, fsmc

I'm trying to use TFT display with ILI9341 8080 16 bit interface with STM32F407 via FSMC. I'm using HAL. To explain a bit more, for ILI9341 command registers only lower 8 bits of the bus are used, full 16 bit bus width is only used for transfer of image data (in RGB 565 format). I tested the program before with identical display configured with 8080 8 bit interface and it worked flawlessly.

I have image data in MCU memory in `uint16_t` format and use

```
HAL_SRAM_Write_16b
```

for transfer of image data and

```
HAL_SRAM_Write_8b
```

for transfer of commands and command parameters.

Now, when I select

```
hsram1.Init.MemoryDataWidth = FSMC_NORSRAM_MEM_BUS_WIDTH_8;
```

everything works fine, only image data (colours and resolution) are wrong of course, because ILI9341 has only lower 8 bits of data (blue and half of the green bits) and upper 8 bits are zero. As soon, as I select

```
hsram1.Init.MemoryDataWidth = FSMC_NORSRAM_MEM_BUS_WIDTH_16;
```

display shows black and grey stripes for a second and then just goes white – error state.

I use A16 for command / data selection, therefore address of command memory is `0x60000000` and data memory `0x60010000`, hopefully same for 8 bit and 16 bit bus width?

**Question:** Can anybody explain to me, how data transfer in `FSMC_NORSRAM_MEM_BUS_WIDTH_16` mode works, more precisely when I use `HAL_SRAM_Write_16b` (or `HAL_SRAM_Write_8b`) in this mode, if the data are sent one 16 bit (or 8 bit aligned to lsb) word per time frame, or if the MCU somehow distorts / combines them.

Comment: How are the IM pins (to select the interface mode) configured on your display? There are 8 different parallel bus options between 8/9/16/18-bits and either mode I or mode II for all of them.

Comment: @brhans I'm using ER-TFTM024-3 display on pre-made PCB from buydisplay.com on which IM pins should be already connected. According to [datasheet](http://www.buydisplay.com/download/manual/ER-TFTM024-3_Datasheet.pdf) it should be 8080 16-bit mode I.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that address bits differ between 8-bit and 16-bit addressing mode. In 8-bit addressing it's mapped to bits `[0-23]` and in 16-bit to `[1-24]`, so if you want to use `A16` pin as CMD / DATA selection, the address of DATA transfer is `0x60010000` in 8-bit mode and `0x60020000` in 16-bit.

Source: STM32F4 Reference Manual: 36.4.1 NOR/PSRAM address mapping